# Error: password_hash(): Password must be a string in laravel

Tags: string, laravel, hash, passwords, password-hash

An ErrorException occurred in my code $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
 saying password_hash(): Password must be a string. I am using laravel framework

```
            $user = new User();
            $user->username = Input::get('username');
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));   
             if($user->save())
             {   
                return Redirect::route('home')->with('success','You register successfully. You can now login');
             } else {
                return Redirect::route('home')->with('fail','An error occurred while creating user. Please try again.');
             }
```

Comment: You should edit your question and put there your form code

Comment: Probably `Input::get('password')` does not contain any value, so i would check if your HTML form really has an input field with this name.

Comment: @martinstoeckli I've checked it earlier but it seems even if you have no inputs at all you won't see such error.

Comment: I've that kind of problem also.Is that fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue, using wamp 2.4 which comes with PHP 5.4, but after upgrading to wamp 2.5 which comes with php 5.5, it was solved so thats solution number 1:

- If you are running a lower version of php then you might want to upgrade.

Still looking for a solution that doesnt require an upgrade because on Laravel's documentation, it mentions that 5.4+ is supported for Laravel 4.2

Comment: i encountered this on hhvm, any solutions ?

Comment: never mind, just cast the parameter you pass in to Hash::make() to string.. calling Hash::make(123) will cause this error while Hash::make('123') does not

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on a Linux machine which threw in

```
ErrorException
password_hash(): Password must be a string
```

By upgrading PHP from PHP 5.4 to PHP 5.5 it solved it on my Laravel environment.